# Touch ID fingerprint identification

Tags: ios, biometrics, touch-id

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to get the fingerprint name after a successful authentication? the public api doesn't look like to have this sort of functionality.

I just want to identify which finger is used for authentication (either using public or private api)

Comment: Submit a radar bug with apple. We really do need this, both the names and an fingerprint unique ID.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a feature that is accessible (publicly or privately).

Apple is very security conscious in this area - in Settings, it's behind a passcode.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're assuming fingers are named, you cannot get the name of the finger, but even if you could, what use is it when the user has to rename each finger to whatever makes sense for them?

I've seen people name the middle finger the "f*** you finger", and the thumb the "guitar stroker". On a test device my index is named "Daniel Index", and other person being "Giuliano Index" for instance.

The hardware doesn't know if a finger is a thumb or an index. So, maybe you've assumed too much from the Touch ID to begin with.

Comment: assume you want to implement a system where a device can be used between multiple people (I know its not intended that way) so you want to know who is the person (finger) being authenticated. I know there's a "Touchy" app which launches an app based on each finger. just google it

Comment: Touchy is a jailbroken app. But it does beg the question, just how does it do that? I'd say that there is a private data structure with those names available.